# What exactly is an analytic curve in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, curves

Regarding the behaviour of conformal maps along the boundary, we had a definition of an analytic curve. I just can't wrap my head around this definition. It goes as follows:

A connected curve $\Gamma \subset \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is called analytic, if there is an injective parametrisation $\gamma\colon[a,b)\to \Gamma$ which, for every $t\in(a,b)$, has an injective holomorphic continuation in a neighbourhood $B_δ(t)$ with $\delta=\delta(t)>0$.

Comment: Are you quoting the definition exactly? Did your source really put the quantifier at the end?

Comment: No, it didn't. Sorry, I am seeing right now that formulated like that, the definition could be understanded wrong. I changed it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to $\gamma$ being real analytic with non-vanishing derivative at every $t\in (a,b)$.

Comment: Analytic is equivalent to being holomorphic. Hence, your curve is analytic if it is locally given by the restriction of a holomorphic map.